# Not able to hit the endpoint when making a GET request in swift

Tags: ios, swift2

Hello i am trying to make a get request from my server but i am failing to hit the endpoints as i checked my logs and im not even hitting the final endpoint. The endpoint needs an authorization which has been added to the request field. I am attempting to get json values and display them as a table cell. But when i attempt to retrieve the values it return nil. It never attempts to hit the endpoint. I attempted to put a print statement `print("Session)"` to check if it calls dataWithRequest but if fails to do so. Please i am doing anything wrong here?

```
 func getLocalData() -> [[String:AnyObject]] {
        var json:[[String:AnyObject]]?
        let endPoint = "http://******************"

        let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: endPoint)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue(token!, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization-Header")


        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            print("Session") //not able to get in here
            guard let data = data where error == nil else {
                //network error
                print("Error with network: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse//HTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if statusCode == 200 {
                do {
                     print("Here buddy")
                     json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments) as? [[String: AnyObject]]
                   // return json
                }

                catch {
                  print("Error in json")
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()

        print("JSON: \(json)") //prints nil as it never attempts to make the request to the server

        return json
 }
```

and in my TableListController i attempt to call this function and it complains about the `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

```
class DealListController: UITableViewController {
    let myDeals = DealList()
    var dealsArray = []

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
         dealsArray = myDeals.getLocalData()! //complains about error here
   }
}
```

Comment: Your endpoint is http:// or https://?

Comment: @DanhHuynh http. I deployed server on heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let add these things into your Info.plist
[image]

**Update**: Let use completion handler instead of returning a value

```
func getLocalData(completion: (json: [[String:AnyObject]]?) -> Void) {
    let endPoint = "http://******************"

    let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: endPoint)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization-Header")


    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        print("Session") //not able to get in here
        guard let data = data where error == nil else {
            //network error
            print("Error with network: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            completion(json: nil)
            return
        }

        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse//HTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if statusCode == 200 {
            do {
                print("Here buddy")
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments) as? [[String: AnyObject]]
                // return json
                completion(json: json)
            }

            catch {
                print("Error in json")
                completion(json: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

And:

```
myDeals.getLocalData { json in
    print("json: \(json)")
    dealsArray = json!
}
```

Comment: but i want to return the value, how do i go about that

Comment: The `getLocalData` function will return json immediately before the task complete, so json always be nil and the app crash

Comment: that was my guess. So how can i avoid this. I need to return the values in my DealListController. Please how do i go about that

Comment: You can not return the values by using dataTask

Comment: so when you are using MyDeals.getLocalData is that some form of closure? Sorry im very new to swift. Is the json the parameter in completionHandler as defined in getLocalData?

Comment: yes, exactly! In my code above, the `print("json: \(json)")` will be print when the task is completed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127464/discussion-between-user3497437-and-danh-huynh).